# What is the correct notation for stating that random variables X and Y are independent?

Tags: correlation, independence, notation

Often people put down $X\perp\ Y$ as independence, but this merely means that the expectation of X and Y is zero and does not have any implication on correspondence between their joint PDF, CDF and marginal PDF, CDF, etc...

Is there a widely agreed upon notation for saying that two RVs are independent?

Comment: `\perp\!\!\!\perp` yields $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ which is often used to denote independence, e.g. $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\require{txfonts}$As you say, the use of $\perp$  (`\perp`) for independence is not good, since it often means orthogonal, which in probability theory translates to correlation zero.  Independence is a (much) stronger concept, so needs a stronger symbol, and sometimes I have seen $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ `(\perp\!\!\!\perp)` used. That seems like a good idea!

OK, seems like math markup here does not like `\Perp`, but it is defined in $\LaTeX$ packages `pxfonts/txfonts`.  It is like `\perp`, but with double vertical lines.  Above I replace a hack.

Comment: Good answer. You saw the root of the problem that a lot of people doesn't seem to be able to get.

Comment: I fixed the notation with ideas from:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26231/how-can-i-use-latex-symbol-perp-from-pxfonts-txfonts-in-mathjax?noredirect=1#comment103480_26231

Comment: So it would be \perp\!\!\!\perp, yielding $\perp\!\!\!\perp$.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from multivariate normal distributions of the kind $(X,Y)$, where one can write $Cov(X,Y)=0$, one writes "$X$ and $Y$ are independent". Why bother with symbols if normal language is already clear and short?

Comment: It is only for _jointly_ normal random variables that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ can be used as a substitute for saying $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Is there much saving in stating "$X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal random variables with $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ and means $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ and variances $\sigma_X^2, \sigma_Y^2$ respectively" versus "$X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ are independent random variables"?

Answer (score 1):

$X|Y = X$ does not reflect the symmetry of the (non-)relation but shouldn't it signify independence?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user78740. Was this intended as an answer to the OP's question, a comment requesting clarification from the OP or one of the answerers, or a new question of your own? Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers to the original question. You will be able to comment anywhere when your reputation is >50. If you have a new question, click the gray `ASK QUESTION` at the top of the page & ask it there, then we can help you properly. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: I read this as a definite answer--but it's dangerous to pose answers as questions, for people misinterpret the intention and vote to close them. Regardless, there is an interesting distinction operating here: "$X|Y=X$" may indeed *imply* independence, but it appears to do so by virtue of a mathematical argument: it does not in itself *signify* independence (unless you actually define independence in terms of conditional distributions, which is a bit unusual).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, old answers. However, I'm using the Unicode character [U+2AEB](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aeb/index.htm):

⫫